# using iBeacons in Xamarin Android apart from Activity

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, ibeacon-android

I have a Xamarin Forms app where one of the pages s being rendered natively on Android.

```
 public class ConnectIBeaconRenderer : PageRenderer , IBeaconConsumer
{
//How to implement IBeaconConsumer here?
}
```

As above how do I implement IBeaconConsumer inside that page renderer? 
When Implementing in an activity all you have to implement is

```
 public void OnIBeaconServiceConnect()
    {
      //Only needs implementing this when inside an activity. 
    }
```

In my case as I stated I am not on an activity but on a Page Renderer. How do I implement the remaining members of IBeaconConsumer?

```
public Context ApplicationContext
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public bool BindService(Intent intent, IServiceConnection serviceConnection, Bind flags)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void UnbindService(IServiceConnection p0)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Found this https://github.com/rosekl/xamarin-ibeacon-demo/blob/master/BeaconDemo/BeaconDemoAndroid/BeaconLocaterAndroid.cs probably it should help

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Xamarin expert, but when doing the equivalent natively in Android, you solve this by chaining methods from another `Context` object.  You need to figure out a way to pass a valid `Context` object from an Activity or your application into your `ConnectIBeaconRenderer` class using a custom constructor or setter.  Once you have this you do:

```
public Context ApplicationContext
{
    get
    {
        return context;
    }
}

public bool BindService(Intent intent, IServiceConnection serviceConnection, Bind flags)
{
    return context.BindService(intent,service connection,flags);
}

public void UnbindService(IServiceConnection p0)
{
    return context.UnbindService(p0);
}
```

Comment: yes similar to that. The link in my comment helped me